# Initialize core data managedObjectcontext

Tags: ios, core-data, singleton

I am using a singleton data controller to call my core data functions from two different views: create view and history view.

A First view just has create or view history buttons to go to respective view.

My problem is that I have to go through my create process (press create Care in create view) to receive anything from Core data in my history view. I therefore assume that I have to initiate my managedObjectContext. Or do I need to init some other core data element?

I init the dataControllerSingelton in appDelegate. I can not however figure out how to Init the managed object context in my single init method:

```
+(DataControllerSingleton *)singleDataController{

static DataControllerSingleton * single=nil;

@synchronized(self)
{
    if(!single)
    {
        single = [[DataControllerSingleton alloc] init];
        single.masterCareList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[DataControllerSingleton singleDataController] managedObjectContext]; - This lame attempted does not work


    }

}
return single; }
```

my managedObjectContext method in singletonDataController.m :

```
 - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
 {
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

After I run this create Care method it works fine:

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(Care *)care{


NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];

NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:    
[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSString *fileName = care.pictureURL;
NSString *text = care.causeText;
NSDate  *date = care.date;
NSData  *imgData = care.imageData;

[newManagedObject setValue:fileName forKey:@"urlPath"];
[newManagedObject setValue:text forKey:@"name"];
[newManagedObject setValue:date forKey:@"date"];
[newManagedObject setValue:imgData forKey:@"imageData"];

 // Save the context.
[self saveContext]; 
}
```

Any feedback or tip is helpful, I very much appreciate detailed code as well!

Answer (score 2):

You are fine, this should work. You are correctly creating managed object context lazily, so it should just get created if it is not there yet.

I think your singleton is absolutely **overkill**. It would make sense to use the Apple boilerplate to initialise the core data stack in the app delegate and then just give your view controllers a simple `managedObjectContext` property.

Very simple, there are dozens of example projects like this from Apple. Unless you are synching asynchronously with iCloud, you don't have any use for the singleton.

Comment: I agree, your setup looks fine, you should just use a print statement or breakpoint to check the status of your NSManagedObjectContext after the initializer. There are a few design elements that I would tweak though. Firstly, as @Mundi said, this is overkill. The only reason I would use a singleton for core data is if I had a more complex core data structure in which case, **the singleton would not actually pass out its managedObjectContext.** I would use it to get an instance of a child context that I could use to do background imports and processing.

Comment: Nothing happens when I debugg this line: NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[DataControllerSingleton singleDataController] managedObjectContext];

Comment: .... it just skips it and moves on. 

I started out without singleton but then someone pitched the singelton idea and I wanted to try it. I might rebuild actually :/

Comment: "Nothing happens...": you mean the context is `nil`? In this case your singleton method does not work. As stated before, best refactor without singleton.

Comment: I thought I solved it by changing self. to single. in the @synchronized method. i.e:  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [single.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
This works and my context is initialized and I can do count etc. but now when I push create new care it is not included until I close the app. The save context method is triggered but I think I have multple threads with different contexts! Or what do you think? I dont want to abandon the singleton yet.

Comment: My synchronized method:     @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!single)
        {
            single = [[DataControllerSingleton alloc] init];
            
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [single.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
            
            single.masterCareList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        
    }
    return single;
}

Comment: @Mundi any other suggestions besides removing the singelton?

Comment: No, without the singleton you are all set.